# Kendo DropDownList Tooltip on focus

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-tooltip

Is there any way how to show tooltip on Kendo DropDownList on **focus**? Hover works, click works but focus not. I want to implement Bootstrap popover to DropDownList, but it seems that Kendo Tooltip doesn't work too.

```
<input id="myInput" class="k-group" />


$("#myInput").kendoDropDownList({}).data("kendoDropDownList").wrapper.find(".k-input").kendoTooltip({ 
  content: 'tooltip tooltip tooltip', 
  showOn: 'focus' // DOESN'T WORK
  //showOn: 'mouseenter' // Works fine
  //showOn: 'click' // Works fine
});
```

https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/ZXzOwQ

EDIT:
I want to know, why focus method doesn't work. Is it unsupported option for DropDownList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show it manually:

```
var e = $("#myInput")
    .kendoDropDownList({})
    .data("kendoDropDownList")
    .wrapper
    .find(".k-input")
      .kendoTooltip({ 
        content: 'tooltip tooltip tooltip', 
        showOn: 'mouseenter click'
      });

e.closest(".k-widget").on("focus", function() {
    $(this).find(".k-input").data("kendoTooltip").show();
});
```

<del>[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXzpMX)</del>

**UPDATE:**

Better yet, create the tooltip in the `wrapper` instead of `.k-input`:

```
$("#myInput")
  .kendoDropDownList({})
  .data("kendoDropDownList")
  .wrapper
  .kendoTooltip({ 
    content: 'tooltip tooltip tooltip', 
    showOn: 'mouseenter click focus'
  });
```

[Updated Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXzpMX)

Comment: Not solution for me. As I said I need to implement other tooltip, but just trying to find out why only focus method on dropdown doesn't work. If it is not supported or where is the problem.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be working. Tried this before (using wrapper to attach tooltip) and it failed somehow for me. So ok, thnx.